# React Redux Firebase: firebase.auth(...).signOut(...).then(...).error is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-redux, dispatch, react-redux-firebase

This one particular firebase function hasn't worked for me when calling it as an action. Login, edit username, register, all of those work fine... except logout.

After looking at some tutorials and Google's own documentation, I thought this function would work like all the other firebase-auth functions I've implemented.

Here's what my actions to the db look like:

```js
/* AuthUser.js */
export const login = credentials => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS });
        dispatch(push('/home'));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, err });
      });
  };
};

export const logout = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS });
        dispatch(push('/login'));
      }) /* ERROR POINTS RIGHT AT THIS LINE */
      .error(err => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_FAIL, err });
      });
  };
};

export const register = user => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then(res => {
        return res.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: user.displayName,
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS });
        dispatch(push('/login'));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAIL, err });
      });
  };
};

export const save = displayName => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (displayName !== '') {
      user
        .updateProfile({
          displayName,
        })
        .then(() => {
          dispatch({ type: SETTINGS_NAME_CHANGED });
          dispatch(push('/home'));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch({ type: SETTINGS_ERROR, err });
        });
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: SETTINGS_LEFT_ALONE });
      dispatch(push('/home'));
    }
  };
};
```

Here is how I'm setting up my connects in the Component that calls some of these functions.

```js
/* Settings.js */
import React from 'react';
import { /* Some Stuff */ } from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import 'someStyles.scss';
import { logout, save } from '../store/actions/authUser';

class Settings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      displayName: '',
    };
  }

  /* This doesn't! */
  onLogout = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout();
  };

  /* This works! */
  onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.save(this.state.displayName);
  };

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { displayName } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container className=".settingsBody">
        <nav>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://github.com">GitHub</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink>
                <div onClick={this.onLogout.bind(this)}>Logout</div>
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </nav>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="displayName">Change Display Name</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="text"
              id="displayName"
              placeholder={this.props.auth.displayName}
              value={displayName}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button color="primary">Save Settings</Button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

Settings.propTypes = {
  logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  save: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  authError: PropTypes.string,
  auth: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    authError: state.auth.authError,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    logout: () => dispatch(logout()),
    save: displayName => dispatch(save(displayName)),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Settings);
```

React throws this error: `TypeError: firebase.auth(...).signOut(...).then(...).error is not a function` Yet other functions run as expected when ran.

Is there something I'm missing? The code will attempt to navigate to the page I want but throws the error before that page properly mounts.

Comment: You did catch() everywhere else, why did you do error() there?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I figured it would be something stupid, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

Promises doesn't have `.error` callback, it should be `.catch`.

Read about [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)